# Jdk 8 http upload speed issue

Tags: java, java-8, apache-httpclient-4.x, okhttp

I write simple java code upload file to web server. It running smoothly with jdk7 (upload speed about: 20 MB /s), but when i switching to JDK8 upload speed down to 2MB/s.
I have tested and it same result with apache httpclient, okhttp (windows and linux)
Could you help me solve this issue.
this is simple code using apache  http client

```
    FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity (file,
            "application/octet-stream");
    final RequestBuilder preUpload1 = RequestBuilder.post()
            .setUri(new URI(upload_url)).setEntity(fileEntity)
        ;


    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(preUpload1.build(),
            new StringResponseHandler());
```

Comment: That's a very difficult answer to solve without knowing your correct setup. And even then, we would have to replicate that. Have you tried uploading a smaller file an look at the Wirecast snippet? Can you see anything in the server log while uploading (errors, wrong packets, etc.)? Can you make detailed measurements of the performance, maybe the message preparation is taking more time (how do you measure the time)?